# How to download GitHub repo as Zip without using Git

Tags: git, bash, shell, unix, github

I'm writing a script for a server which needs to download a GitHub repo, but Git is not installed on the server and I do not have sudo privileges to download it, so I can't simply Git Clone the repo.
Is there a way for me to obtain the repo as a Zip without using a Git command?

I've tried:

```
curl -O -L 'https://path/to/repo.git'
```

But this just downloads a .git file and I'm not sure if there's a way to extract the files from this?

I've also tried:

```
wget https://path/to/repo.zip
```

Which downloads a Zip folder, but it's actually just some ASCII text and when I attempt to unzip it it fails to recognise it as a Zip folder.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can download the repository contents at any tag or branch.

For example see this page with .zip download links: https://github.com/django/django/tags

You see the link has format `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/archive/<ref>.zip`, where ref is tag, but it can also be branch (like `master`).

So this works:

```
$ wget https://github.com/django/django/archive/master.zip
```

Answer (score 3):

Github gives you an option to download as zip without having Git installed on your local machine. 
Check out the image below

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this from the script though?

Comment: @tnoel999888 the zip file URL is deterministic, so you can build the URL in the script.

Comment: right click on the download zip button to copy the zip URL.
Replace that URL here `wget copiedURL`

Answer (score 0):

On Apr2023, an uptodate answer is :

1. Click on (1) in the pic (click on the label "Code" ). The example project site tested here is : https://github.com/slembcke/debugger.lua  ;
2. Click on (2) in the pic first if you can't see where to click in 1) - guide   (that is, if you don't see the label "Code" ).

[Where to click on github to get ZIP file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YXs8.png)

Comment: Links don't stay up forever. It's best to write out the answer here instead of relying on an external resource.

Comment: Thanks. Your reminder made me think and I've found 2 simple solutions for needed pictures : normal camera or some computer tricks. So I'll try soon to improve the answer if I get the right.